# what is maximum elevation an android view can have?

Tags: android, view, android-5.0-lollipop

In Android 5.0 material design **elevation** came for every view ,

I want to know what is max elevation size we can have and why its counted in **dp** and not direct pixel ?

Answer (score 3):

Elevations are in `dp` for the same reason all other dimensions are in `dp` -- pixels can't represent physical dimensions without taking into account display density.

There is currently no enforced maximum `elevation` value, but at some point you'll get close enough to the camera elevation that it will look terrible. In general, I don't think the Material guidelines recommend any elevations greater than `16dp`.

Comment: The docs have some examples that go up to 24dp - e.g. a dialog picker - https://material.io/design/environment/elevation.html#elevation-in-material-design